# Closed form for $Q_{m}(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{ (-1)^n}{n+m}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, closed-form

I've just stumbled upon this
$$
Q_{m}(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{ (-1)^n}{n+m}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}
$$
and i'd like to know if it has a closed form.

Note that $m \geq1 $ is an integer.

Thanks.

Comment: Given the very fast decrease of the coefficients, I doubt it.

Comment: This looks like we need the coefficient of $x^{-m}$ in the product $e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^{k=\infty} \frac{x^{-(m+k)}}{m+k}$

Comment: Note that $$(x^mQ_m(x))'=x^{m-1}e^{-x}$$ and $Q_m(0)=\frac1m$ hence $$Q_m(x)=x^{-m}\int_0^xt^{m-1}e^{-t}dt$$

Comment: @Did, which is essentially lower incomplete gamma function $Q_m(x)=x^{-m}\gamma(m,x)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: @YuriyS Which is mostly *giving a name* to a formula.

Comment: @Did, with additional formulas and references which might be useful

Comment: This appears to be the Laplace transform of $e^{-e^{-s}x}$ from $s$ to $m$. So $Q_m(x)= \int_0^\infty e^{-e^{-s}x-ms}\;ds $.